# OpenID for mono 2.8

Tags: mono, openid, dotnetopenauth

Does a OpenID library that works on mono 2.8 exist? I tried DotNetOpenAuth, but it fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go to DotNetOpenAuth's source code repository, they have a Mono branch that works on Mono.  That's what I use for http://wrench.mono-project.com/.

Comment: Thank you, it works! I wish I knew it two days ago. Yesterday I even tried to recompile openid4java via ikvm to use it on mono)

Comment: would you be interested in helping me update that mono branch?  Some "bugs" in mono keep me from updating that branch regularly but perhaps with your expertise we can get it done.

Comment: I tries the version mono2, on some providers it works, but on google it fails with error 'No OpenID endpoint found', do you know to fix it? I use mono 2.8 (tarball Sun Oct 31 08:12:53 UTC 2010) and mod_apache.

Comment: Google works for my site, so I don't know.  You might want to see if the DotNetOpenAuth people have any ideas.

Comment: Here is the Google OpenID site I use, dunno if that helps: https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id